# Operands to ?: have different types with matching auto functors

Tags: c++, functor, auto

I have the following, which does not compile:

```
void func(std::optional<std::function<void(int, int)>> arg1)
{
    return;
}

void callee(bool flag)
{
    auto arg1 = [](int a1)
    {
        return;
    };

    auto arg2 = [](int a1)
    {
        return;
    };

    func(
        (!flag ? std::optional{arg2} : (flag ? std::optional{arg1} : std::nullopt)), 
        std::optional{arg2});    
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    callee(true);
}
```

For the following reason:

> error: operands to '?:' have different types 'std::optional<callee(bool)::<lambda(int)> >' and 'std::optional<callee(bool)::<lambda(int)> >'

Explicitly defining the type of either `arg1` or `arg2` instead of using `auto` allows this to compile.

Why is the compiler unable to deduce that they are in fact the same type?

Comment: Lambda is syntax sugar over class with `operator()`, so each lambda is in fact its own unique type, even if they are identical.

Comment: BTW, you have *"typo"*, 2 args expected for `std::function`, but 1 args for each lambda.

Comment: "_Explicitly defining the type of either arg1 or arg2 instead of using auto allows this to compile._": It is impossible to explicitly specify the type of the `arg1`/`arg2` variables in their definition. "_Why is the compiler unable to deduce that they are in fact the same type?_": They are not.

Comment: why use ternary ? `if (condition) func(a); else func(b);` poses no artificial restictions upon `a` and `b`. The ternary is not just a tool to make code shorter

Comment: A three-legged conditional with a boolean condition seems a bit excessive. (You basically have `if (!flag) {...} else if (flag) {...} else {...}`

Comment: Your conditional is strange: the `nullopt` case will never be triggered. So if you really want to use a conditional you could do `func(std::optional{flag ? arg1 : arg2});`.

Answer (score 2):

lambda is not `std::function`. You have 2 different lambdas (even if code is identical), and so 2 different types.